# Kafka: NoBrokersAvailable cuándo intento conectarme a Kafka desde un host externo

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, kafka

Estoy intentando conectarme a un servidor VPS(111.111.111.11) Ubuntu dónde tengo Kafka configurado, a otro servidor VPS(222.222.222.22) Ubuntu dónde estoy usando Python para conectarme a Kafka.

Si uso mi aplicación Python en el mismo servidor dónde tengo instalado Kafka no tengo problemas en hacer una conexión correcta. Sin embargo, si intento conectarme desde el servidor externo me es imposibe.

Este es mi `docker-compose.yml` dónde Kafka está funcionando:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.2
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2
    container_name: broker
    ports:
    # To learn about configuring Kafka for access across networks see
    # https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9093:9093"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_EXTERNAL://222.222.222.22:9093
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

Y este es mi `app.py` de mi código de python que uso para intentar conectarme a Kafka:

```
import json, time, requests
from flask import Flask, render_template

from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from kafka import KafkaProducer

import threading, queue

from src.messages import processMessage

ORDER_KAFKA_TOPIC = "senderTopic"
ORDER_CONFIRMED_KAFKA_TOPIC = "receiverTopic"

app = Flask(__name__)

q = queue.Queue()

producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers="111.111.111.11:9093"
)

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    ORDER_KAFKA_TOPIC,
    bootstrap_servers="111.111.111.11:9093"
)


def worker():
    while True:
        message = q.get()
        consumed_message = json.loads(message.value.decode())
        message_id = consumed_message['data_id']
        ts = int(time.time())*1000

        print(f"{ts}:[SUCCESS]:[{message_id}]:Successful message received...")

        processMessage(consumed_message)
        q.task_done()



def load_consumer():
    print("Gonna start listening...")
    for message in consumer:
        try:
            q.put(message)
            
        except Exception as e:
            pass

@app.before_first_request
def launch_consumer():
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()


@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

launch_consumer()
load_consumer()
q.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Entonces, cuándo intento conectarme con este código desde mi servidor externo recibo `NoBrokersAvailable` pero si lo hago desde el interno dónde se encuentra Kafka, funciona sin problemas.

**EDIT**

Ambos son servidores Virtuales Cloud, cada una con una IP diferente. Son servidores de Ubuntu20.04.

¿Podrían ayudarme?

Comment: El servidor donde está kafka tiene algún firewall definido? Están en la misma LAN? Están en un servicio en la nube? Las respuestas son infinitas sin saber cómo están desplegados esos dos servidores

Comment: @Alfabravo usé ufw para permtir los puertos, incluso probé deshabilitando el firewall, pero me rechazaba la conexión. Añadí esa información ahora la consulta

Comment: Sigue sin ser evidente la situación de los dos servidores. Pueden tener el firewall deshabilitado pero no sabemos qué camino se necesita para llegar de un lugar al otro. Revisa de nuevo mi comentario y edita tu pregunta nuevamente. Omite cualquier dato específico que comprometa la seguridad de tus servidores.

Comment: Editado, muchas gracias @Alfabravo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Resulta que dónde tenía subido ambos servidores, tienen un firewall externo que se edita desde la propia configuración del servidor de manera externa.

Tuve que habilitar el firewall en las configuraciones del servicio dónde tengo instalado los servidores.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que la cosa sea de cómo Kafka escucha las peticiones.

En el enlace que aparece dentro de tu docker-compose ([este](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/)), indican que para hacerle binding al broker con tooodas las interfaces de la máquina, puedes usar `0.0.0.0` en `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`. Con eso, no tienes que lidiar con el hecho de que la VPS no necesariamente tiene asociada la IP pública que indicas (eso puede estar dado por la infraestructura de red del hosting, que resuelve eso mucho más arriba en el stack a una IP privada)... de hecho, yo ejecutaría `ip addr sh` en una terminal con SSH a tu VPS 222.222.222.222 para ver si esa IP está por ahí (yo apuesto a que no).

Adicional a eso, no se entiende el listener `PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092`, pues no estás mapeando ese puerto en ninguna parte :) En la documentación te dicen claro que tienes que mapear ese puerto en la definición del contenedor

```
…
    ports:
      - "19092:19092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,CONNECTIONS_FROM_HOST://localhost:19092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONNECTIONS_FROM_HOST:PLAINTEXT
…
```

para que el contenedor también exponga eso, lo mapee a un puerto lógico del host y Kafka broker lo pueda usar.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, las Ips que puse, 111.111... y 222.222... son para no comprometer mis Ips, si en ambos servidores hago `ip addr sh` me aparecen correctamente las Ips de mis servidores, lo que no quería era exponer mis servidores.

Respecto al listener `PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092" he usado lo que me aparecía en la docu.

He conseguido que me funcione de manera interna (desde el mismo host dónde se encuentra docker) y ahora me faltaría hacer la conexión con el servidor externo (imaginandonos que la IP es 222.222...), quizás no me expliqué bien, perdoname